# Search in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I have a table of "posts" with attributes that include `title` and `body`.

posts_controller.rb:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search], params[:id])
  end
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
 <%= form_tag posts_path, :method => 'get'  do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search]%>
   <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil  %>
 <% end %>

<hr />
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><hr></td>
  <td><hr></td>
</tr>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>

    <tr>
      <td><%= post.title %></td>
      <td><%= post.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', :action => :show, :id => post.id %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', :action => :edit, :id => post.id %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', { :action => :destroy, :id => post.id }, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><hr></td>
      <td><hr></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

and post.rb

```
def self.search(search, id)
 if search
   where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
 else
  scoped
 end
end
```

When I submit the search params, I get an error message:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Posts#index 
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: name: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE (name LIKE '%lorem%') 

Extracted source (around line #23):

23:   <% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

APD: I want to search by 'title'.

Comment: If you want to search by title why do you use a `name` column, which apparently doesn't exist?

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer since it's definitely the problem here ;)

Comment: Tell me plz for what we need :title => nil  in view?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Although this is not a direct answer to your question, here are some resources that may help you as you are learning about search and getting it implemented in your Rails app.

[A Simple search form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form/)

[Advanced search form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form/)

[Searching with AJAX](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax)

[Powerful search functionality with the Sunspot gem](http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot)

[List of the most popular search tools for Ruby](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=search)

---------------UPDATE----------------

Elasticsearch has been growing in popularity due to some modern awesomeness that it has, such as instant indexing. It has a ruby gem named tire. Definitely worth a look.

[Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)

[Tire](https://github.com/karmi/tire)

---------------UPDATE 2----------------

Tire has been retired, and has been replaced by [Elasticsearch-ruby](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby)

Comment: @Richard Thanks for the suggested update regarding tire being replaced.

Comment: It was renamed, appropriately, to 'retire'

Comment: Isn't "A simple search form" open to SQL Injections?

Answer (score 13):

For people coming here and looking for a solution in Rails 4, try the following example:

Posts Controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:search]
      @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end
  end
end
```

Post Model:

```
def self.search(search)
  # Title is for the above case, the OP incorrectly had 'name'
  where("title LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

The index.html.erb remains the same apart from the search form:

```
<%= form_tag(posts_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Posts" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Note that the paths, controllers and columns you are using may be different.

Answer (score 10):

Elasticsearch with gem **searchkick**

**note**: searchkick is also contributed by tire) makes you more comfortable to work on.

For more refer:

[SearchKick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick)