# Select object where attribute is true having attribute name in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a problem with Sqlite in Ruby on Rails. I have a model with some boolean attributes. I get the name of the attribute (the column in the database) from the view and I need to select all the objects which have that attribute set to **true**.
From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010780/rails-how-to-do-search) topic I found out that, as for the search query, I need to write this:

```
def self.search(search, id)
 if search
   where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
 else
  scoped
 end
end
```

I imagine that the query would be very similar, but I really don't know how to communicate it to the database. Any suggestion?

Comment: Something like: `@posts = Post.where(boolean_attribute: true)`??

Comment: What is your `model` and the `boolean attribute` name? And you should be doing like what @justin suggested.

Comment: Oh, allright. I thought I should pass through the model... I'll try

Comment: How are you submitting the name of the column?

Answer (score 1):

The topic you linked has nothing do to with your problem.

Assuming the name of your attribute is a string and stored in `params[:attribute]` and `Post` is your model.

In your action

```
@posts = Post.where(params[:attribute].to_sym => true)
```