# self.search body Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search

In Rails I'm trying to create an additional **Search** field for a **Articles** project in which the 2nd search field searches the Articles **Body** and `not the Title!`

**Look at the project here**
https://glacial-island-18918.herokuapp.com/

## index.html.erb

```
    <div id="main">
     <%= form_tag articles_path, :method => 'get' do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search Title" %><br><div>
       <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-success" %>
        <% end %>

     <%= form_tag articles_path, :method => 'get' do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :body, params[:body], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search Body" %>
       <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-success" %>
        <% end %>
```

## Article.rb

```
    def self.search(query)
     # where(:title, query) -> This would return an exact match of the query
       where("title like ?", "%#{query}%")
    end
```

## ArticlesController.rb

```
    def index

     @articles = Article.all
     @markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML)

    # Adding search feature for Title.
      if params[:search]
         @articles = Article.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
      else
         @articles = Article.all.order('created_at DESC')
      end
    end
```

I've searched through these Stack Posts but can't seem to find an answer(I would have posted more but because my reputation is low I can only post two links.)

[Search in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010780/search-in-rails) ==> But it only talks about getting the search to work correctly for the title, no mention of the body

http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form/ ==> This one sorta had what I was looking for but this seemed a lot more difficult to me, not simply searching for through another column of the row in the table; searching the **Body** column instead of **Title** column.

I've tried adding different methods to the Article.rb model, Articles_controller.rb, but I'm just shooting in the dark; `any suggestions Stack family?`

`Your help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! =)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the most elegant solution, but here's an easy way to do it.

First, change your view to use different keys for title and body searches (`title_search` for title and `body_search` for body):

```
<div id="main">
 <%= form_tag articles_path, :method => 'get' do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :title_search, params[:title_search], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search Title" %><br><div>
   <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-success" %>
 <% end %>

 <%= form_tag articles_path, :method => 'get' do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :body_search, params[:body_search], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search Body" %>
   <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-success" %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Then change your controller to

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all
  @markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML)

  if (title = params[:title_search].presence) || (summary = params[:body_search].presence)
    @articles = Article.search(title: title, body: body).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @articles = Article.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end
end
```

Finally, update your `search` method to take a hash:

```
def self.search(query_hash)
   result = all
   result = result.where("title like ?", "%#{query_hash[:title]}%") if query_hash[:title]
   result = result.where("body like ?", "%#{query_hash[:body]}%") if query_hash[:body]
   result
end
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer!
I tried doing what you suggested and it seems as if it didn't work(although I'm known to error so lemme try again). It appears to be returning everything now.

Licecap video I threw together:
     http://imgur.com/a/2Ov82 
Sourecode can be viewed here:
     https://github.com/PrimeTimeTran/blog

Comment: Probably the params are not being passed correctly, so you're searching with a `nil` in the `LIKE` sql which will return everything.

Comment: I think you'll need to permit `title_search` and `body_search` in the controller. Do you have `params.permit(:search)` right now in there somewhere?

Comment: I've looked at your code and there are a few things you need to fix. First thing is that you did not copy the view code from here correctly: you still have `text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-con
trol", placeholder: "Search Title"`, but this should be `text_field_tag :title_search` and `params[:title_search]` (see my code above). The other thing is that my `search` method above had some issues, please update to the code I have now. The code should then work.