# How to search for user in Ruby on Rails using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have implemented user's authentication using devise. I have created Group model, to which I want to add user's. To implement that I want to have a search box which will search for user's account by his email or nickname. I know how to make a GET request but I don't know how to search for user using devise.

Comment: It is actually not a Devise issue. You just work with your User model (or how it named in your project) as usually. It is just a model with attributes.

Comment: So generally speaking can I use GET to the controller which will pass data from model to the view? Because I found this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Find-a-user-when-you-have-their-credentials and tbh I don't know whether it's correcty or not

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a general question about how to make a search field in Rails.

A User model from devise acts like any other model when it comes to querying data in the database (and almost anything else).

First question to ask is if you want it to be an Ajax search or a normal HTTP request.

Both has their ups and downs.

A good example: [creating a search form](https://medium.com/@zylberberg.jonathan/creating-a-search-form-in-rails-5-77fdef6be74d)

Or you could read about more basic form_helpers and GET methods in the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#a-generic-search-form)

### Added

This has some very good examples!: [Search in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010780/search-in-rails) (stackoverflow answer)