# Ruby on Rails: How to implement search function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I'm very new to Ruby on Rails and actually, I'm trying to implement a search function into my Ruby on Rails page. It's a page where you can add users to a database, you can also edit or delete them. There is my index page where all of those users are getting listed, and, above this table, there is a search function (well, it's just a text field and a button).

What I want to do it now: I want to implement a search function which is searching for the surname, room, key, manager and so on. I already tried some things but I finally don't know how to implement a search function in general (what should I write, where should I write it? I heard from models and controllers, but anyway I'm not 100% sure). I would be really pleased if you could help me through this!

Cheers,
absolado

Comment: You need to just fire a query for the entered keyword and list them in the same page or a different page.

Comment: you may find your answer for your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12011246/2256370)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a gem for this in case you do not want to implement it yourself. [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) is a very popular gem which can support all this functionality along with helpers for your views, advanced search matchers and many more. I suggest you have a look on this before proceeding with your own implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Here below is the sample code of simple search.

index.html.erb

```
<% form_tag projects_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

here your_model.rb

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

here your_controller.rb

```
def index
  @projects = Project.search(params[:search])
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Should I let that @projects and projets_path still there or do I need to change it? Well, I'm not such an expert. And... how can I show the results of that search? I really want to show the results of the search in my users table (current shown users not seeable anymore, now there are the results. There it should also be possible to sort the results - same thing like you can do with your standard users table.

Comment: what's the ```:all``` and ```:conditions``` means?

Comment: `find(:all, :conditions => [...])` has not been a thing since Rails 3.2. Instead you need something like `where('name LIKE ?', "%#{filter}%")`. And the `<% form_tag` needs to be `<%= form_tag` with an equals, otherwise it wont render anything to the page.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for [Datatables](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails). I have used this many times in my apps. Aside from searching an attribute in your records, it also has sortable column feature.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to outline that Datatable is a javascript package which builds a robust table with filter, order, pagination goodies but by default it is not done server-side.

Which means that if you have a large dataset then you might be in trouble as all your records will be pumped to the client's browser as a huge json and Datatable will parse and fill in the table for you.

Datatable provides support to server-side pagination, filter and so on, but then you will have to implement those features into your back-end.